# Understanding about templates and function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, static-methods

> I would like to know Why have to make fun1() as static member function? function pointer in template? in below piece of code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int temp;
    public:
    A():temp(1){}
    template<class T, void (*fn)(T* )>
    static void create(T *ptr)
    {
        cout <<"create fn"<<endl;
        //fun1(ptr);
    }
    static void fun1(A* tp) 
    {
         cout<<"func temp"<<endl;
    }
    static void fun2(A& ob)
    {
        cout<<"fun2 start"<<endl;
        A::create<A,&A::fun1>(&ob);
        cout<<"fun2 end"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A ob,ob1;
    ob.fun2(ob1);
}
```

Comment: see [static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) and see [pointer to function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions)

Answer (score 2):

A static function member of a class is simply a regular function in the class's namespace:

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the program.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

In your example, the type of `A::f1` would be `void(A*)` and the type of `A::f2` would be `void(A&)`. Notably, static functions do not need an instance to be called.

Alternatively, non-static member functions *do* require an instance to be called. You would have to use [pointers to class members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer). In your example, you would use `&A::f1` and `&A::f2` and their types would be `(void)A::*f1(A*)` and `(void)A::*f2(A&)` respectively. If pointers to member functions were treated as regular function pointers, how would they be called? They would need an object instance for the `this` pointer to point to.

You can convert a pointer to a member function to an object that overloads the `()` operator and behaves like a function (AKA a functor) using std::bind:

```
A a;
std::bind(&A::f1, &a); // &a is the value of this
```

However, functors do not have the same type as function pointers. I recommend using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in the `functional` header file instead of function pointers because they accommodate for functors.

(See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer for more information.)

Comment: `std::bind` does not create a function pointer, it creates an object of class type that can be called like a function.  Also, lambdas are superior to `std::bind` in several respects.

Comment: Huh, thanks for telling me. However, don't lambdas also return functors?